# Loop through dynamic xmlType in oracle

Tags: xml, oracle, loops

i have a procedure with XMLType  as Input Parameter and i wanna to select Data from dynamic XmlType parameter passed to Procedure  and Fill it With Cursor (dynamic mean nodes names change each time i call Procedure)
i can select the nodes if i know the nodes name   using  the following code :

```
     SELECT extractvalue(column_value, '/row/id') 
     "id",extractvalue(column_value, '/row/name') "name"
     FROM( TABLE(XMLSequence(XMLTYPE('<root><row><id>id1</id><name>mm</name> 
     </row></root>').extract('/root/row'))))T ;
```

But i  want to select all nodes in xmlType without needing to know nodes names and but data into Cursor

Comment: Isn't all nodes just the original XML?  Please clarify.

Comment: each time i call the Procedure i need to pass xmlType  whatever the node it in Put all Data in cursor

Answer (score 0):

If what you are looking for is to get all elements in xmltype (all xml tags ?) then you could use the [DBMS_XMLDOM package](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/d_xmldom.htm#i1076719).

Just a simple example to show the logic (most probably you would also need to validate child elements and such):

```
DECLARE 
  xml_record      XMLType; 
  cntElements     integer; 
  doc             dbms_xmldom.DOMDocument;
  tagList         dbms_xmldom.DOMNodeList;
  tag             dbms_xmldom.DOMNode;

BEGIN 

 -- !!! xmltype record from a test table with one record !!!;
  select * into xml_record from xmltypes_test;

  -- get xml elements / tags
  doc     := dbms_xmldom.newDOMDocument(xml_record); 
  tagList := dbms_xmldom.getElementsByTagName(doc,'*');

  -- count tags
  cntElements:= dbms_xmldom.getlength(tagList);

  -- loop over tags
   FOR i IN 0 .. cntElements - 1
    LOOP
        tag := dbms_xmldom.item(tagList, i);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line('Element ' || i || ' name: ' || dbms_xmldom.getnodename(tag) );

    END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Hope this helps a little